# Finding the Distribution of Y given $X_1 + X_2$ where X, Y ~ Poisson $\Lambda$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So, because this is honestly homework for a course, I'm primarily looking for a hint from where I've gotten so far. The question is very quick.

> $X, Y$ are independently distributed Poisson $(\lambda)$, find the distribution of $$Y^* = Y\mid X_1 + X_2 = t$$

So, the logic I've gotten to so far, but not really further is the following:
$x_1 + x_2 \sim$ Poisson$(\lambda + \lambda)$.

And that's it. Our professor gave this as a hint but I'm not sure how it was reached.

$$\frac{P(X_1 = x_1, x_2 = x_1)}{P(x_1+x_2=t)}=\frac{P(X_1=x_1,x_2=x_1)}{P(x_1=x_1)P(x_2=t-x_1)}$$

And I very may well have just written the hints down incorrectly. Please advise.

Comment: Are you saying: Let $Y^* = Y|X_1+X_2$. Find the distribution of $Y^*$?

Comment: Presumably what is meant is $\Pr(Y\mid X+Y=t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We give a somewhat expanded version of your professor's hint, correcting some errors of transcription.

For convenience of typing I will call your $Y^\ast$ by the name $W$. We want an expression, preferably nice, for the probability that $W=w$.

Note that by the defining formula for conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(W=w)=\Pr(Y=w\mid X+Y=t)=\frac{\Pr(Y=w\cap X+Y=t)}{\Pr(X+Y=t)}.$$
The random variable $X+Y$ is Poisson with parameter $2\lambda$. Thus we can write down an expression for $\Pr(X+Y=t)$.

For $w=0$ to $t$, we have 
$$\Pr(Y=w\cap X+Y=t)=\Pr(Y=w)\Pr(X=t-w).$$
Now compute, *and simplify*. The final result, after simplification, will be nice.

Comment: So, what particularly does $PR(X=t-w)$ mean?

Comment: It is the probability that $X$ has value $t-w$. Since $X$ is Poisson, the required probability is $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{t-w}}{(t-w)!}$. You will need this in your calculation.

Comment: It is getting late here, so I will not be able to deal with further questions before tomorrow.  After a fair bit of simplification, you should reach the conclusion that $\Pr(W=w)=\binom{t}{w}\cdot \frac{1}{2^t}$. So the distribution of $W$, that is, the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X+Y=t$, is binomial, like the number of heads when  a fair coin is tossed $t$ times.